# DrawerNavigator is not working in Android Studio ADB and physical Device but working in expo?

Tags: android, react-native, navigation

following is simple code which is not working in Android studio and my Device but working fine in expo. There is no error while running code but DrawerNavigator is not working(not showing on swipe on screen). I have installed and link all required package manager
(react-navigation, react-native-gesture-handler)

```js
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, Button} from 'react-native';

import {createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer, createDrawerNavigator} from 'react-navigation';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AppContainer/>
    )
  }
}

class WelcomeScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style = {{flex:1, alignItems:'center',
      justifyContent:'center'}}>
        <Button title='Login' onPress = {() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Dashboard')}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class DashboardScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style = {{flex:1, alignItems:'center',
      justifyContent:'center'}}>
        <Text> DashboardScreen </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Dashboard:{screen:DashboardScreen}
})

const AppswitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  Welcome: {screen: WelcomeScreen},
  Dashboard: {screen: AppDrawerNavigator}
});


const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppswitchNavigator);
```

Console warning is as follows. I did not understan what it exactly means.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9BLy.png)